# values not inserting into db while using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli to try and retrieve the teacher's username and then insert all of the values into the dataabse. The problem though is that nothing is being inserted into the database.

I am getting no errors in my error report so I think I am just doing something wrong when it comes to inserting values into the database using mysqli but I am not sure what. Can anybody give me any pointers on why it is not inserting values into the db?

Below is the code:

```
$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

$sql = "SELECT TeacherId FROM Teacher WHERE (TeacherUsername = ?)";

$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_SESSION['teacherusername']);

$stmt->execute(); 
$record = $stmt->fetch();
$teacherid = $record['TeacherId'];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

{

$time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), array(':', ':', ''), $_SESSION['durationChosen']);

  $insertsql = "INSERT INTO Session (SessionId, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room) 
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

 $insert=$mysqli->prepare($insertsql);

 $insert->bind_params("sssssssss", $sessid, $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
                     $_SESSION['textWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
                     $_SESSION['module'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);


for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i) {
    $sessid = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
    $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

    $insert->execute();
}

$insert->close();

}
```

Comment: I said there is no error in the error report

Comment: $insert->bind_params has 10 values, $insertsql - 9 params

Comment: @AlexeyKa Are sure because it looks like 9 values in bind_params and 9 params in $insertsql

Comment: Sorry ;о) What say $mysqli->error?

Comment: @AlexeyKa There is no error appearing on the page

Comment: it is displaying a fatal error now stating this: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_params() in /web/stud/xxx/Mobile_app/insertsession.php on line 149

Comment: Try to use this: "if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {" instead of "if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {".  mysqli_connect_errno() is for procedural mysqli_connect?

Comment: @AlexeyKa I found out the reason for the fatal error was that it said bind params when it should be bind param. I am getting no error now but still not inserting into database. The query is correct as that when I used old mysql it worked, but when I try using mysqli, then that is where the problem occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug this thing line by line:

- set your error reporting to `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in php file or `error_reporting = E_ALL` in php ini
- does the db connection work ?
- echo the sql query before using it
- it the query seems to be correct: rebuild it to ONE value and rebuild it step by step to find out where's the error

Comment: Ok I will try and debug it and see what is happening but I definetly do know the db connection is correct.

Comment: haha found some activity, it is displaying a fatal error stating this: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_params() in /web/stud/xxx/Mobile_app/insertsession.php on line 149

Comment: I found out the reason for the fatal error was that it said bind params when it should be bind param. I am getting no error now but still not inserting into database. The query is correct as that when I used old mysql it worked, but when I try using mysqli, then that is where the problem occurs